# I need a grails quartz sample project

Tags: grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler

I just need a sample project that uses Quartz or a good tutorial that explains everything step by step.

Answer (score 5):

Fortunately, the [Grails Quartz Plugin Page](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz) is very explicit about how you can create a Quartz job in Grails.

First, become familiar with the `Job` and `Trigger` difference in [Quartz Documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/), then you'll understand immediately how to set these up in Grails

In short, `Job` is WHAT you're going to do (calling databases, sending emails, crawling web pages, etc) and `Trigger` is WHEN you want to do that

A job is useless if it's not launched by a trigger, and 'nothing' will be done if you have a trigger without a job.

What you want to do has to be implemented in the `execute()` method of the `GrailsJob` whereas the `static triggers` field determine which triggers will launch your job. There are several kinds of [triggers](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/), but the more useful is the `CronTrigger`